# Adding string to bound field

Tags: asp.net

trying to add a prefix before bound field

```
<label><input type="radio" name="rbGroup" value='r<%#((Type)Container.DataItem).ID %>'/><%# ((Type)Container.DataItem).Action %></label>
```

but it's putting r next to the button.  I want rID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

value='<%#"r"+((Type)Container.DataItem).ID %>'